# A Selenium method that returns attributes

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm looking for a solution in selenium RC how to return html attributes.
Basically I want to search certain regex on the page, and once the regex has been found I wand to employ a method that returns attribute of html tag containing the regex.

So far I've found a method **storeAttribute**, but this method takes an locator as argument. In my case I don't know in advance where the certain element will occur.

Thank' in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a parser like [JSoup](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsoup.org%2F&rct=j&q=Jsoup&ei=rtV1TeqDDoSnrAeL6p2_Cg&usg=AFQjCNGlZWM77KWn7rklyQkcisWaUuAq0w&sig2=i-hDqRINTQKHB0PkQQlOCg&cad=rja)?
This is for java, but I am sure there would be options in other languages also.

Comment: Java is language I use for selenium rc, so no need for me to look after different language parser... Haven't worked with it. I'll give a try. Thnks!

Comment: If this answers your question then could you please mark it as answered?